# What User-Agent should be used to fetch Open Graph data?

Tags: http, http-headers, facebook-opengraph

The title pretty much sums it up.
I am wondering what User-Agent I should use for **consistent** results when using the Open Graph api.

So far I have been using the client's User-Agent, but that proved to be unreliable as on YouTube for example, when on mobile most of the og fields were missing.